# Method of finding threshold in Decision tree for continuous data

Tags: machine-learning, weka, implementation

I am using decision tree in Weka and I have some continuous data, so when I use Weka it automatically find the threshold for me but for some reason I want to implement Decision Tree by myself so I need to know what approach to use to find the threshold to discretize my continuous data?